# JPA entities are not created in reverse engineering

Tags: java, jpa

JPA entities are not created in reverse engineering, if the table is having foreign key to other table and that other table is having composite key and multiple foreign keys

EX:
Table1 (1_id as PK)
Table2 (2_id as PK)
Table3 ((3_id,1_id,2_id) combination as PK) and having foreign keys for table1 and Table2
Table4 ((4_id,3_id) combinaiton as PK) and having foreign key for table3

Here through JPA reverse engineering , JPA entities are created for table1,table2,table3. But Entity is not created for Table4. But in persistance.xml it added entity entry for Table4 as well.

Comment: Lookup embedded entities in JPA.

Comment: Check for options of embedded entities. Reverse engineering is just via a Plugin you most likely installed in your IDE. Check out for latest versions or other plugins for the JPA, if you cant figure out. However, if it's not created, it's not a programming question rather a tool usage or so. You can very well, create entity of your own.

Comment: Who knows what is 'jpa reverse engineering'. The jpa spec provides no such thing

Comment: Check this out: https://jonamlabs.com/how-to-use-hibernate-tools-maven-plugin-to-generate-jpa-entities-from-an-existing-database/